# Обновление коллекции WPF в параллельном потоке

Tags: c#, wpf, многопоточность, mvvm

Есть приложение WPF на C#. Одна из операций - обновление содержимого `ObservableCollection` в классе вьюмодели достаточно длительная и при этом постоянная (обновляется раз в несколько секунд). Что бы не станить UI решил вывести в отдельный поток при помощи `async` - `await` - `Task`. Код :

```
    private async void ResetAsync()
    {
        await Update(); 
    }
    private Task Update()
    {
        return Task.Run(async ()=> 
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Do some...
                await Task.Delay(2000);
            }
        });
    }
```

Однако возникает проблема связанная с тем (поправьте если не прав), что коллекция вьюмодели должна обновляться внутри UI потока а не того который я выделил через `Async`-`Await`

> Данный тип CollectionView не поддерживает изменения в своем SourceCollection из потока, отличного от потока Dispatcher.

Теперь мне нужно использовать `Dispatcher` что бы вернуть результат в UI поток? Подскажите как это сделать ?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65544/discussion-on-question-by----wpf---).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделайте сервис, например:

```
public interface IContext
{
   void Invoke(Action action);
   void BeginInvoke(Action action);
}
```

И его реализация:

```
public sealed class WpfDispatcherContext : IContext
{
    private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;


    public WpfDispatcherContext()
        : this(Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher) { }

    public WpfDispatcherContext(Dispatcher dispatcher)
    {
        this._dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }


    public void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        this._dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }

    public void BeginInvoke(Action action)
    {
        this._dispatcher.BeginInvoke(action);
    }
}
```

Далее регистрируйте его в своем DI контейнере и подтягивайте на вью модель:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    private readonly IContext _context;

    private ObservableCollection<string> _values;


    public IEnumerable<string> Values => _values;


    public ViewModel(IContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }


    private async void ResetAsync()
    {
        await Update(); 
    }
    private Task Update()
    {
        return Task.Run(async ()=> 
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Do some...

                _context.Invoke(() => _values.Add("New String Value"));

                // Do some more...
                await Task.Delay(2000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Если вы не используете DI контейнеры, то просто ручками в конструкторе вью модели создайте экземпляр сервиса. Это потом можно будет легко исправить, когда вы начнете использовать DI контейнеры:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    _context = new WpfDispatcherContext();
}
```

Comment: Что такое `DI`- контейнер ?

Comment: @Сергей а как у вас подтягиваются сервисы? Или вы хардкодите их создание в каждой вью модели?

Comment: еще вопрос - что понимается под сервисом?

Comment: @Сергей интерфейс `IContext` и его реализацию `WpfDispatcherContext ` я называю сервисом (по факту он выполняет роль сервиса)

Comment: @Сергей, "минимальный самодостаточный ответ" который вас устроит - замените всю работу с коллекциями в таске на "делегирование" этой работы диспетчеру. Т.е. каждый `Collection.Add(i)` заменяется на `await App.Current.Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => Collection.Add(i))` и т.д

Comment: @Сергей обновил ответ.

Comment: Ну заче-е-ем?! Зачем делать свой велосипед, когда есть стандартный класс SynchronizationContext?